# How to include styles when rendering page on server?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, server-side-rendering

I have a problem implementing server side rendering. I'm using react + typescript frontend and backend written in node.js with typescript as well. I cannot find a way to include styles in my page when it's send from the server for the first time (before js loads). What I've tried is bundling all my styles into single main.css file and then using link tag in html file send from server, but in this scenario it takes as much time to load css, as it takes to load js (what is the purpose of SSR here ?). Also i'm trying to avoid styling my component inline. Any help would be apprecieted. Here I'm sharing some of my current code in case it might be helpful in some way.

```
App Component <- optimally i would like to see styled app as soon as browser reads .html file (i guess that's 
the purpose of SSR)


export default class App extends React.Component<State, Props> {
state: State = {

}

render = () => {
    return (
        <div className="app">
            APP COMPONENT !!!
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Client code entry (ClientEntry.tsx)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "../shared/containers/App";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Webpack config

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

const clientConfig = {
  stats:'errors-only',
  entry: "./src/client/ClientEntry.tsx",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "./build/bundle.js"
  },
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "build/media/[name].[ext]",
          publicPath: url => url.replace(/build/, "")
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: { importLoaders: 1 }
            },
            {
              loader: "postcss-loader",
              options: { plugins: [autoprefixer()] }
            }
          ]
        })
      },
      {
        test: [/tsx?$/],
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "build/css/[name].css"
    }),
    new WebpackShellPlugin({
      onBuildEnd: ['nodemon build/server.js']
    })
  ]
};

const serverConfig = {
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({ terserOptions: { mangle: false } })],
  },
  stats:'errors-only',
  entry: "./src/server/index.tsx",
  target: "node",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "./build/server.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "build/media/[name].[ext]",
          publicPath: url => url.replace(/build/, ""),
          emit: false
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "css-loader/locals"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: [/tsx?$/],
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = [clientConfig, serverConfig];
```

Part of index.tsx (express main file)

```
server.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  const body = renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  res.send(
    html({
      body
    })
  );
})
```

And function that converts to html

```
const html = ({ body }: { body: string }) => `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <title> my app</title>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0">
      <div id="app">${body}</div>
    </body>
    <script src="/bundle.js" defer></script>
  </html>
`;

export default html;
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you're using express, which has a built in method to serve static files (such as images, css, etc...) you just need to show it the path as follow

```
server.use('static', express.static('css'))
```

which basically serves all files inside the css folder under the link

```
http://${host}/static/
```

if you want to serve static images you can do the following.

```
server.use('images', express.static('images'))
```

and then you can refer to any image file inside your code using the following.

```
<img src="/images/<image_name>" />
```

You can read more about it here.
[express static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: That's completely not the problem I'm facing. I know how to serve static files. If you know the concept of SSR I'm displaying prepopulated page before js scripts loads.
What i'm trying to achive is diplaying this page with styles so that it doesn't look like crap.